# Email Markup for Events has stopped working

Tags: google-schemas

The email markup has been working really well and our clients love it. A shame MS don't do what you do.... however in the last week or so it has all stopped working.

The events are there in the email and displayed as normal at the beginning of the email but nothing is being populated in the Calendar. This happens on my account and other accounts from other domains (customers). I have also made a booking for a Yoga Class, not connected with `noreply@ebookingonline.net` and that shows the same behaviour. i.e. shows the event but no sync in cal.

I have checked all of the settings in GMAIL and CAL but they're are all ok.

It looks very much like an issue at Google do you have any suggestions?

Here is the schema code extracted from an email sent today. The event is shown as an EVENT before the email is displayed as normal - but nothing in the calendar.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"EventReservation",
    "reservationId":"19198",
    "reservationNumber":"19198",
    "underName":{
        "@context":"http://schema.org",
        "@type":"Person",
        "name":"John Smith",
        "email":"naxxx@XXXXXXXXX.co.uk"
    },
    "reservationStatus":"ReservationConfirmed",
        "reservationFor":{
            "@context":"http://schema.org",
            "@type":"Event",
            "name":"Tennis Booking",
            "startDate":"2024-03-12T11:30:00+00:00",
            "endDate":"2024-03-12T12:00:00+00:00",
            "performer":{
                "@context":"http://schema.org",
                "@type":"Organization",
                "name":"Fantasy Tennis &amp; Squash Club'ss"
            },
            "location":{ 
                "@type" : "Place",
                "name" : "Fantasy Tennis &amp; Squash Club'ss",
                "address" : {
                    "@type" : "PostalAddress",
                    "streetAddress" : "Fantasy Tennis &amp; Squash Club'ss",
                    "AddressCountry" : "Fantasy Tennis &amp; Squash Club'ss",
                    "addressLocality" : "Fantasy Tennis &amp; Squash Club'ss",
                    "AddressRegion" : "Fantasy Tennis &amp; Squash Club'ss",
                    "postalCode" : "Fantasy Tennis &amp; Squash Club'ss"
                }
            }
        },
        "cancelReservationUrl":"https://ebookingonline.net/box/1",
        "modifyReservationUrl":"https://ebookingonline.net/box/1"
    }
</script>
```